# angular-meteor css minification missing in universal example with --production flag or even after meteor deploy

Tags: angular-meteor, angular-universal

Server rendered pages contain non-minified css and served without gzipping. Can anyone suggest a solution to cater this as when I include material 5.0.0-rc0 and some of my css in the application then the static server rendered page size reaches to at least a 300kb.

package.json:

`"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.3.0",
    "meteor-rxjs": "^0.4.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"`

Compiler Versions:

`angular-compilers@0.2.8_1
angular-html-compiler@0.2.8
angular-scss-compiler@0.2.8
angular-typescript-compiler@0.2.8_1
babel-compiler@6.24.7
babel-runtime@1.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding material theme files to global stylesheet main.scss in client folder in your application source files.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I regret that it's not working :(. please visit [link]https://foc-promos.herokuapp.com for a live demonstration.  You may notice that the `main.html i.e list` file size is more than 300kb.